# AccessibilityService running or not check not working

Tags: android, accessibility

I had written a code to check if my AccessibilityService is running or not and based on the result, the text in text view must change to ON/OFF.

This was my code:

```
 public boolean Running() {
        String enabledServices = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ENABLED_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICES);
        String[] runningServices = enabledServices.split(":");
        for (String runningService : runningServices) {
            if (runningService.contains(DisplayService.class.getName()))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

but this code is not working from 7.1.1 anymore. What changes can I do to this to make it work. The current version of android I am using is android 7.1.2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"**

configure the service using an XML file

```
<accessibility-service
     android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeViewClicked|typeViewFocused"
     android:packageNames="com.example.android.myFirstApp, com.example.android.mySecondApp"
     android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"     android:notificationTimeout="100"
     android:settingsActivity="com.example.android.apis.accessibility.TestBackActivity"
     android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
/>
```

Comment: Where should I add this code? And what should I change in the code above?

Comment: If you go the XML route, be sure to reference it in your manifest, by adding a <meta-data> tag to your service declaration, pointing at the XML file. If you stored your XML file in res/xml/serviceconfig.xml, the new tag would look like this:
<service android:name=”.MyAccessibilityService”>
<intent-filter>
<action android:name=”android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService” />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name=”android.accessibilityservice”
android:resource=”@xml/serviceconfig” />
</service>